# Kendo UI Login password text boxes hidden on Windows mobile cordova app

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, windows-phone

I have a cordova 6.0.0 app. My login password form displays ok on Android and IOS but on windows phone 8.1 the input text box and password box are hidden behind the next list item such that you can only see the top of the input text box. When I click on the thin visible text box, it slides up and I am able to see the whole text box. On entering the user name, I have to click on the password box for it to become visible.

Tried setting the margin and padding but the the text boxes do not fully show.

Any ideas on which kendo css attribute is required.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a Kendo Dojo?  They have a windows phone simulator.  http://dojo.telerik.com/

Comment: When I reproduce in dojo, layout is fine, both labels and input fields fully visible. On Windows phone 8.1, clicking in the entry fields make them scroll up so that they fully display. Its like there is some kind of transistion on click taking affect.

Comment: Did you select the Windows Phone simulator in the Dojo?

Comment: Yes, I had selected the windows 8.1 simulator.